# Auto insert text into outlook appointment

Tags: c#, ms-office, outlook-addin

I want to have a few lines automatically added to the subject and body of a new appointment when a user clicks the button to create the meeting. I think this should be done using an office outlook add-in but not sure. I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Basically, when someone clicks the new appointment or new event link within outlook, I want some of my text to appear in the subject and body of the window that pops up.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to create a COM addin (start at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=36)

You will be able to create a custom button on the Outlook ribbon/toolbar. Or you can just trap the Application.Inspectors.NewInspector event, check if the new item (Inspector.CurrentItem) is an appointment, and populate the AppointmentItem.Subject and the AppointmentItem.Body properties.

Answer (score -1):

Use `mailto:email@example.com?subjct=Testing subject` in href of a tag

Comment: I'm using c#.net for windows forms or outlook add-ins (whichever is the better way), not using asp.net. Also, this is for creating calendar events/meetings not for sending emails.